# Change level of manual fold?

Tags: key-bindings, folding, manual-folding

How do you increase or decrease the level of the current, manual fold? And what is the keyboard shortcut to do it?

I cannot see anything in the manual about this. Foldlevel seems to concern not the level of the current fold but the level of folds visible/open.

Comment: You might try `:help usr_28`; I think only marker-based folds can control their depth textually.

Comment: Yes, I had become confused by the name of the unrelated `foldlevel` option and the fact that one of my manual folds had got itself at level 2 without my consent. I reckoned then that I must move it up a level. But since each fold's level is defined by whether and where it is nested in another fold, the way to move it up a level is to 'delete' it with `zd` (the unfortunately-named command for *removing* folds).

Answer (score 0):

The level of a fold is determined by its position in relation to other folds. If it is nested inside another fold it's level is one greater than the level of the fold it is nested in.

That is, if a fold is created at a place within another fold, then it will be nested within that fold, and will be at a level one greater than it.

If you have the `foldmethod` option set to `manual` you can decrease the level of a fold simply by removing it, using the unfortunately-named delete fold command `zd`.

Delete the fold and the lines within it will then become part of the fold above, if there is one, since they would then be at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

- `zm` -  Increase fold level by one
- `zr` -  Decrease fold level by one

#### Some tips

- `zM` sets foldlevel to infinite / close all open folds
- `zR` sets foldlevel to 0 / all folds will be open.
- If you work a lot with folds, use the `:set foldcolumn=[n]` command to have a nice column to the left to see your folds.